# .Net Core Web API project can't connect to SQL Server when debugging in a docker container

Tags: docker, debugging, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I want to preface this by saying that I'm a novice, and a self-taught programmer, and this is only my second project in .net/c#, and my third day of using Docker so I'm sorry if my problem is caused by something very basic, any help is appreciated.

What I'm trying to make is a simple CRUD-enabled API app with .net core using entity framework, and then deploy it using Docker. I have finished the app and it works perfectly when I debug it and use swagger to test the APIs that I created, but only when I am using one of the top two debugging modes [debugging works fine for EMSDocker (name of the project) and IIS Express](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoZ1t.png)

But when I try to use Docker to debug, I manage to get the app to open, but upon executing any API I get the following result:
[What I see when I try to call the getAll API during Dockerized-debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcBMM.png)

to my understanding, the app fails to connect to my SQL Server when it's running in container, and thus the whole thing collapses.

I was initially using a locally installed, Windows authorized MS SQLServer for this (which worked fine for non-container forms of debugging).
My connection string for that db was:

```
"Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog=Employees; Trusted_Connection=true; Integrated Security=true; TrustServerCertificate=True"
```

I later switched to a containerized instance of MS SQL Server following an online guide.
My current connection string is:

```
Server=localhost,1450; Database=Employees; User Id=SA; Password=AVeryDifficultPass123;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;TrustServerCertificate=True
```

This too only works when I'm not debugging in container, and I have no idea what I'm missing.

I'd like to add that I'm very unfamiliar with the docker CLI and I am using the desktop app to view images and containers so far. I tried executing the project with

```
docker build . -t ems
#and
docker run ems
```

and the Visual Studio terminal responded with this [Terminal After executing 'docker run ems'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdDRr.png)
but I couldn't figure out how to observe the app in browser following this.

P.S This is my first post and english isn't my first language so I'm sorry if I don't get my point through clearly, I'd love to answer any questions about things that I may have missed.